# Javascript find time difference in hours with timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have a javascript object with the following details:

```js
var dateobj = {
  date: "2020-12-21 03:31:06.000000",
  timezone: "Africa/Abidjan",
  timezone_type: 3
}

var date = new Date();
var options = {
  timeZone: dateobj.timezone
};
var curr_date = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options)
console.log(curr_date)
//I want this 
//diff = curr_date - dateobj.date
```

I want to find the time difference in hours with the current date-time of the same timezone. I know I can use `toLocaleString()` function to get the date-time string in a particular timezone, but how can I find the time difference? The above code gets the current date time in that timezone, how can I find the time difference in hours?

Comment: What have you tried so far? and what doesn't work?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it with relevant JavaScript you tried and expected output

Comment: @mplungjan     Added the code.

Comment: Parsing a timestamp in a specific timezone is possible but fairly complex to code yourself (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61364310/257182)). Try a library like [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon).

Answer (score 1):

In general when working with dates in JS I usually use a library called `date-fns` (Date functions). It just makes dates and time a lot easier to manage. This is how you would get the time difference in hours with `date-fns`.

```js
const { differenceInHours } = require("date-fns"); 
const { zonedTimeToUtc } = require("date-fns-tz");

const timeData1 = {date: "2020-12-21 03:31:06.000000", timezone: "Africa/Abidjan", timezone_type: 3};
const timeData2 = {date: "2020-12-21 03:31:06.000000", timezone: "America/Los_Angeles", timezone_type: 3};

const t1 = zonedTimeToUtc(timeData1.date, timeData1.timezone);
const t2 = zonedTimeToUtc(timeData2.date, timeData2.timezone);

const diff = differenceInHours(t2, t1);

console.log(diff);
// => 8
```

Run demo: https://runkit.com/embed/jtfu0ixxthy7

Comment: Thank you! I used the moment.js library.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back with a (hopefully) better answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68593283/9761106) does something similar by converting each date with `toLocaleString`, then create 'new Date()' and then subtract the two. Eventually dividing by `6e4` to get the difference in minutes.

For the original example, we would have something like this:

```js
var dateobj = {
  date: "2020-12-21 03:31:06.000000",
  timezone: "Africa/Abidjan",
  timezone_type: 3
}

var date = new Date();
var options = {
  timeZone: dateobj.timezone
};

const curr_string = date.toLocaleString('en-US', options)
const orig_string = "12/21/2020, 03:31:06 AM"
const string1 = new Date(curr_string);
const string2 = new Date(orig_string);
console.log((string1.getTime() - string2.getTime()) / 6e4);
```